# Split string using new line character and append strings using PL SQL function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, split, append

I have a scenario of splitting a string field based on newline character chr(10) using pl sql function with a loop and append a tag to the splitted strings(even if there is a empty string in a line).

```
eg- 1chr(10) 2chr(10) chr(10) 3  should become <a>1</a><a>2</a><a></a><a>3</a>
```

I have achieved it using an sql query in the following manner

```
   Select '<test>'
           || replace('1chr(10) 2chr(10) chr(10)3',chr(10),'</test>'||chr(10)||'<test>') 
           || '</test>'
    From your_table;
```

But I want to get it done using PLSQL function for future uses and if I want to add any other logics. How can I do it using a loop in  a plsql function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for loop` and `regexp` as follows:

```
Declare
  Str varchar2(1000) := '1' || chr(10) || '2' || chr(10) || '3';
  Outstr varchar2(2000);
Begin
  For i in 1.. (regexp_count(str, chr(10)) + 1) 
  loop
     Outstr := outstr ||  '<a>' || regexp_substr(str,  '[^'||chr(10)||']',1,i) || '</a>';
  End loop;
  Dbms_output.put_line(outstr);
End;
/
```

[Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=263533491c826d3ee22d3ec2326d26e1)

Comment: Hi I get the following error " ORA-06550 PKS-00103 encountered symbol LOOK when expecting the following . (), * %="

Comment: ORA-06550 PKS-00103 encountered symbol "LOOP" when expecting the following . (), * %="

Comment: Done. Updated the answer and added the db<>fiddle. Please check now!!

Comment: thanks but when I added blank line. i.e Str varchar2(1000) := '1' || chr(10) || '2' || chr(10) || chr(10)||  '3'; between 2 and 3 I need tags with empty value but empty tags are shown after 3 and not between 2 and 3. How can I change this to catch that empty line?

Comment: Hmm.. that you need to handle using some replace technique in your string before processing anything. I have given answer using considering the sample data and expected output provided in the quesrion.

Comment: actually the sample data has that blank and I mentioned about it in the question is it possible for you to modify the function like putting an if condition? great help

Comment: Actually sample data has a space in that line, not blank. It works as expected if it is blank. - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=15899ddd5181a4898a3692f2bafb53ec

Comment: yes it works but when I put blank line between 2 and 3 the blank tags are show after 3. Like this  <a>1</a><a>2</a><a>3</a><a></a>

Comment: Yes, actually that is not taken care in this solution. You can replace 2 chr(10) with space between 2 chr(10) in str at the start of the pl/sql block and then do the other processing as per my answer.

Comment: I actually dont understand how to generate a string like that with a space using replace function how is it possible?

Comment: Refer this - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a741d8841fa4f0f310ba372f465af30e

Comment: wow your a super genious thanks for the great help

Comment: If it solved your issue then accept the answer so that this question is marked as resolved.

Comment: I tried this Declare
  str varchar2(1000);
  Outstr varchar2(2000);
Begin
 select replace('abc' || chr(10) || chr(10) || 'd' || chr(10) || chr(10)|| 'e'  , 
       chr(10) || chr(10), chr(10) || ' ' || chr(10)) into str from dual ;
 
  For i in 1.. (regexp_count(str, chr(10)) + 1) 
  loop
     Outstr := outstr ||  '<item><linea>' || regexp_substr(str,  '[^'||chr(10)||']',1,i) || '</item></linea>';
  End loop;
  Dbms_output.put_line(outstr);
End;

Comment: but the result was <item><linea>a</item></linea><item><linea>b</item></linea><item><linea>c</item></linea><item><linea> </item></linea><item><linea>d</item></linea>